# How am I still getting an error code, I have copied this copy word for word and still having issues... anyone else get this before?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
with open('recent_tweets_bmw.csv', 'wb', '\r\n') as csvfile: 1
    wf = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for tweet in tweets:
    wf.writerow(['bmw', tweet['text'].encode("utf-8")])[enter image description here][1]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>         4 # to handle text encoding challenges
>         5 
>   ----> 6 with open('recent_tweets_bmw.csv', 'wb', '\r\n') as csvfile:
>         7 
>         8
>
> TypeError: an integer is required

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `'\r\n'` to `open()` as the third *positional* argument. But that is the `buffer` parameter's position (size of buffer). I think you want to use *named parameter* syntax and say `newline='\r\n'` or some such...

Comment: I tried to enter the code that way but only to find that it is invalid keyword?



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b0ee1490c76f> in <module>()
      1 import csv
      2 
----> 3 with open('name-brands.csv', 'w', newline='r\n') as csvfile:
      4     wf = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
      5                             quotechar='"')

TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: You appear to be using python2, despite tagging the question as python-3.x. Perhaps you should set the open mode to 'Uw' or 'Uwb'?

Comment: Thank you!! Got it.